# Webpack Not Bundling Output JS Files

Tags: node.js, webpack, sass, webpack-dev-server, sass-loader

None of the output js bundle files are being created nor show up in the directory, although the output from the terminal says these files are being built...

I have tried following several tutorials in order approach this problem from different angles, but I still cannot figure out what is preventing my output bundle files from being created.

These are the versions I'm running:

- npm - 6.9.0
- Node - 10.15.0
- Webpack - 3.5.6

The following is my webpack.config.js file:

```
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const glob = require('glob');

function tryResolve_(url, sourceFilename) {
  try {
    return require.resolve(url, {paths: [path.dirname(sourceFilename)]});
  } catch (e) {
    return '';
  }
}

function tryResolveScss(url, sourceFilename) {
  const normalizedUrl = url.endsWith('.scss') ? url : `${url}.scss`;
  return tryResolve_(normalizedUrl, sourceFilename) ||
    tryResolve_(path.join(path.dirname(normalizedUrl), `_${path.basename(normalizedUrl)}`),
      sourceFilename);
}

function materialImporter(url, prev) {
  if (url.startsWith('@material')) {
    const resolved = tryResolveScss(url, prev);
    return {file: resolved || url};
  }
  return {file: url};
}


module.exports = [{
  entry: {
    radio: './src/radio.js',
    index: './src/index.js',
    radioStyle: './src/radio.scss',
    indexStyle: './src/index.scss'
    },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: () => [autoprefixer()]
            }
          },
          { loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              importer: materialImporter,
              includePaths: glob.sync('node_modules').map((d) => path.join(__dirname, d))
            }
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      }
    ]
  },
}];
```

The following is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "my-radio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material/button": "^1.1.0",
    "@material/card": "^1.1.0",
    "@material/ripple": "^1.1.0",
    "@material/top-app-bar": "^1.1.0",
    "@material/typography": "^1.0.0",
    "material-components-web": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.5.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "extract-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

As I understand, this code is supposed to output "radio.bundle.js", "radioStyle.bundle.js", "index.bundle.js", and "indexStyle.bundle.js" into my /dist folder:

```js
entry: {
    radio: './src/radio.js',
    index: './src/index.js',
    radioStyle: './src/radio.scss',
    indexStyle: './src/index.scss'
    },
output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
```

But after I npm start and get a "Compiled successfully" message, I can't find these files anywhere in my directory.

This is my project structure:

```
dist

docs
 proj-dir-structure.odt
node_modules
src
 index.js
 index.scss
 radio.js
 radio.scss
bundle.css
bundle.js
index.html
package.json
package-lock.json
radio.html
webpack.config.js
```

Comment: Did you check if you have the `dist` folder anywhere? That's where the files should be

Comment: @HRK44 Yes I do have a `dist` folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `package.json` has below scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
}
```

`npm start` will invoke `webpack-dev-server`. This will build all the files in your dependency graph and keep it `in-memory`. This helps the `webpack-dev-server` to detect change in files and trigger `auto-reload`. The built files will not be available physically

`npm run build` will invoke `webpack -p`. This will generate the output bundle which you would deploy in production. You can find the generated files in your `dist` folder

You have to execute `npm run build` to view the generated webpack output

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Can't believe I didn't think of that sooner.